# Worksheet connection does not import beyond column IU

Tags: excel, xlsx

I am trieng to use a worksheet connection to import data from one workbook into another workbook.
Only when i refresh the data it does not go beyond colum IU (255 columns).

I know this can be an issue when using older Excel formats but both files are MS Excel 2013 files, does anybody has an idea how i can fix this?

Comment: The file format is irrelevant - it will be a limitation of whatever provider you are using for the data connection. Many of the standard ones will not return more than 255 columns from a table.

Comment: Thank you rory, i still dont really get it, When you link two excel documents by using a connection set up in excel, wouldn't it be normal to expect that all data is transferred? Can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: As far as I know, anything built into Office will not return more than 255 columns from one table.

Comment: Thats too bad, can you post the comment as an answer so i can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file format is irrelevant - it will be a limitation of whatever provider you are using for the data connection. Many of the standard ones - including all the ones native to Office as far as I am aware - will not return more than 255 columns from a table.